# Find original color of element before mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bubble chart in which I make bubbles in the following way:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", width / 2)
          .attr("cy", height / 2)
          .attr("opacity", 0.3)
          .attr("r", 20)
          .style("fill", function(d){
            if(+d.student_percentile <= 40){
                return "red";
            }
            else if(+d.student_percentile > 40 && +d.student_percentile <= 70){
                return "yellow";
            }
            else{
                return "green";
            }
          })
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yscale(+d.rank);
          })
          .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
            d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .ease(d3.easeBounce)
              .attr("r", 32)
              .style("fill", "orange")
              .style("cursor", "pointer")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
               texts.filter(function(e) {
                    return +e.rank === +d.rank;
               })
              .attr("font-size", "20px");
            }
           )
          .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
            d3.select(this).transition()
              .style("opacity", 0.3)
              .attr("r", 20)
              .style("fill", "blue")
              .style("cursor", "default");
              texts.filter(function(e) {
                return e.rank === d.rank;
              })
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .ease(d3.easeBounce)
            .attr("font-size", "10px")
          });
```

I have given colors red, yellow, green to the bubbles based on the student percentile. On mouseover, I change the color of bubble to 'orange'. Now the issue is, on mouseout, currently I am making colors of bubbles as 'blue' but I want to assign the same color to them as they had before mouseover, i.e., red/green/yellow. How do I find out what color, the bubbles had?
One way is to obviously check the percentile of student and then give color based on that(like I have initially assigned green/yellow/red colors), but is there any direct way of finding the actual color of bubble?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways for doing this.

**Solution 1:**

The most obvious one is declaring a variable...

```
var previous;
```

... to which you assign to the colour of the element on the `mouseover`...

```
 previous = d3.select(this).style("fill");
```

... and reuse in the `mouseout`:

```
d3.select(this).style("fill", previous)
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var previous;
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 75)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 50 + 50 * i
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i)
  })
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    previous = d3.select(this).style("fill");
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#222");
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", previous)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

**Solution 2:**

However, D3 has a nice feature, called *local variables*. You simply have to define the local...

```
var local = d3.local();
```

..., set it on the `mouseover`:

```
local.set(this, d3.select(this).style("fill"));
```

And then, get its value on the `mouseout`:

```
d3.select(this).style("fill", local.get(this));
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var local = d3.local();
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 75)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 50 + 50 * i
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i)
  })
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    local.set(this, d3.select(this).style("fill"));
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#222");
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", local.get(this));
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

**Solution 3:**

Since DDD (also known as D3) means *data-driven documents*, you can use the bound datum to get the previous colour.

First, you set it (in my demo, using the `colors` scale):

```
.style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.fill = colors(i);
})
```

And then you use it in the `mouseout`. Check the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5).map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d
    }
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 75)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 50 + 50 * d.x
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.fill = colors(i);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#222");
  }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", d.fill);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

For using this solution #3, the element's datum has to be an object.

PS: drop that bunch of `if...else` for setting the style of the bubbles. Use a scale instead.